# Unable to compile C# code on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, compilation, .net-assembly

I am receiving an error when I try to compile my c# source code file on my Mac. Normally I compile my source code using the mcs command on a bash terminal window and it compiles fine. But, this one particular project requires the installation of the NuGet package 'MySql.Data'. This has resulted in the following error message:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MySqlConnection' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have tried to follow numerous solutions online to try and add the assembly reference, but my IDE just does not look like the help documentation's screenshots.

I have tried to Edit References, but no references appear. I tried to manually download the MySql.Data.dll (v.6.3.5.0) but I think it is for an outdated version of the MySql.Data class library as it does not work. Even after cleaning the code and rebuilding it.

**Edit:** I have also tried to add the dll that was included in the project folder but it said it could not locate the assembly (even though they are both in the same project folder).

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "search_feature". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. (MSB3245) (search_feature)

**Edit 2:** I renamed the dll file from the project bin folder to MySql.Data.dll and I no longer get the error. But it still won't compile.

The code works fine when run in Visual Studios for Mac, but I just can't compile it. Any ideas how to add the assembly reference?

I am using the most up-to-date version of Visual Studios:

Visual Studios for Mac Community 7.5.4 (build 3)

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studios for Mac.

My code has the library reference at the top: `Using MySql.Data.MySqlclient;` and the project runs. It just won't compile.

Comment: Switch to ".net assembly" tab, then click "browse" and select your dll file (the one that your working version uses).

Comment: manually adding the dll that was contained in the project's file produced another error, ill add it to the question